# TYPO3: How to count page impressions on every page with an extension

Tags: statistics, count, typo3, impressions

I need to count the page impressions of every page on a TYPO3 site into the db. 
So I think I need an extension which is called on every page impression and increase a column 'impressions' in the db of the specific page.

I'm new to typo3 and new to extension development as well. Is there a way to include an extbase-extension on every page so some php-script get called?

(Update)
I want to add more information:
I don't need a counter which counts all PIs. The counter needs to be page-related. So it make sense to extend the pages-table from Typo3. Another need is that the extension should be done with extbase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm new to typo3 and new to extension development as well. Is there a way to include an extbase-extension on every page so some php-script get called?

Once your plugin is configured you can include it with `page.1234 < plugin.tx_yourextension_pi1` on any page. `1234` determines the position on your page.
The script should be USER_INT, so it's not being cached (mind you, this will cost loads of performance as previously stated by @norwebian)

As you don't want to output anything, make sure the controller stays empty as well.

Comment: Thanks, I marked your answer as right because I've solve my problem this way. Although my solution doesn't use extbase due to a problem with the mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do a quick search in the extension repository? Trying a [search for "page counter"](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/?tx_terfe_pi1%5bview%5d=search&no_cache=1&tx_terfe_pi1%5bsword%5d=page+counter) reveals four relevant extensions.

"Sys_stat" is the closest thing to an "official" solution, it is really just enabling a few settings already existent. It has been reported to fill up the database with too much data, though.

"Generic Visitor Counter" would be my favourite, I believe (if I was going for a page counter at all), it is recently updated and seems simple enough.

You should really consider a proper stats extension, though. Both ics_awstats and ke_stats have been in my toolset.

YMMV. Be aware that if your site is popular, stats gathering quickly gets out of hand. On the other hand, if you go for a simple counter, including uncached extensions will cost performance.

Comment: Existing extension could be nice but doesn't fit my demands. They are "too much" and not programmed in extbase. If I want to include a plugin I've read that including somethink like this `temp.foo < plugin.tx_extension_pi1` in the template would call it on every site. Maybe this will help...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I really understood what you want and need. After all, page impressions are not the same as page views. I wouldn't know the difference "onpage" right now though. So am I right in assuming that you mean page views?

If yes: I would take the following approach:

A separate, autonomous extension with a JavaScript for asynchronous calling of an API and a table for storing page views / page impressions.

Each page globally binds a JavaScript that initializes itself.

- Once the DOM is ready, it sends a call to an AJAX API endpoint with the URL of the page as a parameter.
- The endpoint takes only the URL.
- For each unique URL, a record including counter is created or updated.

Extending the table for the pages doesn't make sense to me. What are you doing with a website that consists of news overviews, news details, press and blog sections, a dealer search and a store with product pages?

I would keep the statistics table standalone.

If you expand the table a bit and add date and time - no simple increment of hits - you can even identify the hottest pages of the week, the month, etc.

--

My approach won't increase/delay page load time much, if at all, and will have little noticeable impact even on heavily requested websites.

With the AJAX endpoint, it's then up to you how you deploy it and how much of the CMS framework you want to load.